# How to fix the HTML/CSS code to look more like my Figma design

Tags: html, css, figma

I am currently trying to convert my Figma design to HTML/CSS code. I used the anima plugin to get the CSS for the page. But the layouts does not seem to align.

[image: My figma design]

The above is my Figma design.

[image: my html output]

The above is my HTML output

the issues I am facing are

1. Don't know which div is for logo EZ. I have the icon image but don't know which class should be in.
2. the tabs buttons are overlapping and also a scrollbar is present

other issues are kind of alright for me. These are the ones I want to fix

```css
.dailymotiv {
  background-color: #181818;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.dailymotiv .div {
  background-color: #181818;
  border: 1px none;
  height: 1080px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1920px;
}

.dailymotiv .overlap-group {
  height: 655px;
  left: 29px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 394px;
  width: 1589px;
}

.dailymotiv .text-wrapper {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Nunito-Regular", Helvetica;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 89px;
  left: 108px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 280px;
  width: 1373px;
}

.dailymotiv .text-wrapper-2 {
  color: #ecfcd7;
  font-family: "Nunito-Regular", Helvetica;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 57px;
  left: 520px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 357px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 348px;
}

.dailymotiv .rectangle {
  height: 655px;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1589px;
}

.dailymotiv .h-1 {
  color: #89c838;
  font-family: "Nunito-Bold", Helvetica;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 63px;
  left: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 137px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1576px;
}

.dailymotiv .line {
  height: 1px;
  left: -8px;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 347px;
  width: 1928px;
}

.dailymotiv .overlap {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(170.78, 255, 63.75) 0%, rgb(24, 24, 24) 83.42%);
  height: 345px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1920px;
}

.dailymotiv .img {
  height: 95px;
  left: 1755px;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 62px;
  width: 95px;
}

.dailymotiv .icon-more-circle {
  height: 60px;
  left: 1677px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 84px;
  width: 59px;
}

.dailymotiv .icon-scan-barcode {
  height: 60px;
  left: 61px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 84px;
  width: 60px;
}

.dailymotiv .icon-home {
  height: 60px;
  left: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 81px;
  width: 60px;
}

.dailymotiv .frame {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #00000040;
  height: 60px;
  left: 111px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 242px;
  width: 1714px;
}

.dailymotiv .div-wrapper {
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 97px;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  left: 1092px;
  padding: 0px 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 375px;
}

.dailymotiv .text-wrapper-3 {
  color: #181818;
  font-family: "Nunito-Bold", Helvetica;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 56px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-right: -17px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: relative;
  width: 272px;
}

.dailymotiv .frame-2 {
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  border-radius: 97px;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  left: 687px;
  padding: 0px 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 375px;
}

.dailymotiv .text-wrapper-4 {
  color: #181818;
  font-family: "Nunito-Bold", Helvetica;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-right: -17px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 272px;
}

.dailymotiv .frame-3 {
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  border-radius: 97px;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  left: 282px;
  padding: 0px 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 375px;
}

.dailymotiv .text-wrapper-5 {
  color: #181818;
  font-family: "Nunito-Bold", Helvetica;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-right: -14px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 269px;
}

.dailymotiv .icon-add-circle {
  height: 127px;
  left: 1709px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 682px;
  width: 127px;
}

.dailymotiv .frame-4 {
  height: 140px;
  left: 1704px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 873px;
  width: 138px;
}

.dailymotiv .rectangle-2 {
  height: 135px;
  left: 874px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  width: 173px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dailymotiv">
  <div class="div">
    <div class="overlap-group">
      <div class="text-wrapper">Text 1</div>
      <div class="text-wrapper-2">Text 2</div>
      <img src="./img/bg.png" alt="" class="rectangle">
      <div class="h-1">Heading 1</div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlap"></div>
    <img class="img" src="./img/user.png" alt="Image" />
    <img src="./img/icon__more_circle_.png" alt="" class="icon-more-circle">
    <img src="./img/icon__scan_barcode_.png" alt="" class="icon-scan-barcode">
    <img src="./img/home.png" alt="" class="icon-home">
    <div class="frame">
      <div class="div-wrapper">
        <div class="text-wrapper-3">Daily Motivation</div>
      </div>
      <div class="frame-2">
        <div class="text-wrapper-4">Notes</div>
      </div>
      <div class="frame-3">
        <div class="text-wrapper-5">Text 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img class="icon-add-circle" src="./img/icon__add_circle_.png" alt="..." />
  </div>
</div>
```